# Posting a like via app on facebook only returns true and does nothing

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I was trying to get the feeds of friends' fan pages with a cURL and to post a like via app.
The cURL GET works fine, but when it comes to liking the object (that has for sure likes enabled because it's facebook), all I get is a boolean (and no action).
I had seen on SO that you post a like with

```
($access_token, "https://graph.facebook.com/$post_id/likes", 'POST')
```

However, it is not working (it says either that the app has no permissions to do that, or that I need a valid url).

I have tried all possible solutions but nothing seems to work. The profile is mine, the access token too, and I gave publish_stream permissions to my own app.

After having given a try to the SDK PHP Likbrary, I tried a direct cURL post, with the following code:

```
function likeit($url){
 //open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

}
```

The execution i a puzzle. When it does not return an OAuth Exception it returns boolean and stops there (there is no way for me to "like" the post I want to like). The last attempt (but I've tried them all, even the whole url in some tests) is

```
foreach ($feeds->data as $feed_data)
$message = $feed_data->message;
$title = $feed_data->name;
$link = $feed_data->link;
$id = $feed_data->id;


    $myaccesstoken = "longlastingaccesstokenstring";
    $post=likeit($myaccesstoken, "https://graph.facebook.com/$post_id/likes", 'POST');
```

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to do this? It seems trivial and yet there is no way for me to accomplish it. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, and thus am posting it here for future reference (hoping it is helpful for anybody with the same problem):
the only problem was that after the new permissions with facebook I needed to re-authorize my app.

After that, it is possible to post a like with the SDK facebook library, normally:

```
             $facebook->api("/$id/likes", 'post', array( 
            'access_token'  =>  $myaccesstoken));
```

No need to use cURL directly. Hope this helps someone with the same question.